# Error when calling bitly api from Google apps script: INVALID_ARG_LONG_URL

Tags: google-apps-script, bitly

Trying to shorten URLs through a Google apps script using Bit.ly api:

```
function shortenURL() {
  var longUrl = 'www.google.com';
  var shortURL;
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify({
      "long_url": longUrl,
    }),
    'muteHttpExceptions': false,
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'xxx (my authorization key)'};
  Logger.log(longUrl);
  shortURL = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", options).getContentText(); // Modified
  Logger.log(shortURL)
}
```

My URL looks fine but Bitly is rejection saying my URL is too long:

```
10:59:40 AM Notice  Execution started
10:59:40 AM Info    www.google.com
10:59:40 AM Error   
Exception: Request failed for https://api-ssl.bitly.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"message":"INVALID_ARG_LONG_URL","resource":"bitlinks","description":"The value provided is invalid.","errors":[{"field":"long_url","error_code":"... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
shortenURL  @ BitlyTest.gs:14
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `options` is not enclosed by `}`. Please be careful about this.
- I thought that `var longUrl = 'www.google.com';` might be `var longUrl = 'https://www.google.com';`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function shortenURL() {
  var longUrl = 'https://www.google.com';
  var shortURL;
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      "long_url": longUrl,
    }),
    'muteHttpExceptions': false,
    'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'xxx (my authorization key)' }
  };
  Logger.log(longUrl);
  shortURL = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", options).getContentText(); // Modified
  Logger.log(shortURL)
}
```

- When I tested this modified script using my access token, I confirmed that the correct response value could be obtained with no errors.

Comment: Right you are - after some cleanup I also narrowed it down to the missing 'https://' prefix. Thanks!